# Splitting Observable<boolean[]> to Observable<boolean>[]?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In a component I have following:

```
// this.can... are booleans
redux
  .watch(state => state.userInfo.access.current)
  .takeUntil(this.done)
  .subscribe(access =>
    [this.canPartners, this.canServices, this.canTens, this.canWorklist] =
    [EPermission.Partner, EPermission.Worklist, EPermission.Tens, EPermission.Worklist]
      .map(ii => access[ii] >= EAccess.Read));
```

I wonder how I can split the Observable to something like that:

```
// this.can...$ are Observable<boolean>s
[this.canPartners$, this.canServices$, this.canTens$, this.canWorklist$] = redux
  .watch(ReduxGetters.userAccess)
  .takeUntil(this.done)
  .?mapSplit?(access => [EPermission.Partner, EPermission.Worklist, EPermission.Tens, EPermission.Worklist].map(ii => access[ii] >= EAccess.Read));
```

UPDATE

I'm on rxjs BTW which means I'm rather limited by the operators provided there. The nearest I got there is the following:

```
const result$: Observable<Observable<boolean>[]> = redux
  .watch(ReduxGetters.userAccess)
  .takeUntil(this.done)
  .map(access =>
    [EPermission.Partner, EPermission.Worklist, EPermission.Tens, EPermission.Worklist]
      .map(ii => Observable.of(access[ii] >= EAccess.Read)));
```

...now I 'just' need to get rid of the wrapper Observable...

Comment: Maybe [flatmap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) is what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like this

```
// this.can...$ are Observable<boolean>s
redux
  .watch(ReduxGetters.userAccess)
  .takeUntil(this.done)
  .reduce((accumulatorArray, current) => {
    accumulatorArray.push(current  >= EAccess.Read)
  }, new Array<boolean>())
  .submit(
    arrayOfBooleans => [this.canPartners$, this.canServices$, this.canTens$, this.canWorklist$] = arrayOfBooleans
  )
```

I could not try this, but maybe it works

Comment: I'm trying to get the destructuring part out of the reactive part.